# Why does OpenAPI hide final fields?

Tags: java, openapi

I am trying to build a REST API from Java objects and controllers in a micronaut app with OpenAPI. I have noticed that final members of a DTO are excluded from the generated descriptor (`swagger-ui.html` in the running app), but I don't understand why.

With this code, all members appear in the API.

```java
public class Overview {
    public String status;
    public Table table1 = new Table();
    public Table table2 = new Table();
}
```

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Overview:
      type: object
      properties:
        status:
          type: string
        table1:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Table'
        table2:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Table'
```

With this one, only the first member is visible, why ?

```java
public class Overview {
    public String status;
    public final Table table1;
    public final Table table2;
}
```

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    Overview:
      type: object
      properties:
        status:
          type: string
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why final members of a DTO are excluded from the generated descriptor in your case is because Micronaut's OpenAPI integration uses the Java Bean Introspection API to generate the OpenAPI specification from your Java classes. According to Java Bean standards, final fields are not considered for the purpose of introspection. This means that final fields will not be included in the generated OpenAPI specification. If you want the final fields to appear in the generated specification, you can use the @JsonProperty annotation from the Jackson library to include them:

```
public class Overview {
    public String status;
    @JsonProperty
    public final Table table1;
    @JsonProperty
    public final Table table2;
}
```

This way, the final fields will be included in the generated specification, and they will appear in the swagger-ui.html.

Comment: The explanation seems good, but it doesn't work. Do you have a reference doc that states that final members are excluded from introspection ?